# Having trouble using graphql's fragments with Apollo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollostack

My problem is quite simple, I need to get different menu functions depending on which type of user is logged in on my app (using react/redux/graphql/apollo).

I have it all working fine, but my graphql query to get the info I need currently looks like this:

```
const currentUsr = gql`
query getCurrentUser {
    getCurrentUser{
        firstname,
        id_users,
        menuItem {
            title,
            url,
            id_parent,
            is_parent,
            icon,
            id_menu_item,
            childs {
                title,
                url,
                id_parent,
                is_parent,
                icon,
                id_menu_item,            
                childs {
                    title,
                    url,
                    id_parent,
                    is_parent,
                    icon,
                    id_menu_item
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
`;
```

It's fairly obvious that I want to use fragments here, to make it look more like this:

my `fragment` would be something like

```
fragment itemInfo{
    title,
    title,
    url,
    id_parent,
    is_parent,
    icon,
    id_menu_item
}
```

and the result I want:

```
const currentUsr = gql`
query getCurrentUser {
    getCurrentUser{
        firstname,
        id_users,
        menuItem {
            ...itemInfo
            childs {
                ...itemInfo
                childs {
                    ...itemInfo
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can't find a simple explanation on the doc, at least I don't get it right. I don't know if I need to create fragments server or client side, and how to properly do it. Can someone comfortable with graphql/apollo help me out on what to do here? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when you write your query, what you want to do is the following.

1. Fragment on a type
2. Specify the behavior on the fragment

To generalize it

```
query {
 _id
 name
 ... on UserType1 {
   #UserType1Fieldshere
 }
 ... on UserType2 {
   #UserType2fieldshere
 }
```

This allows you to request specific fields depending on what type of user you are returning. You probably want to group your users under an "interface type" or a union so you can delineate the relationship.

Here: https://medium.com/the-graphqlhub/graphql-tour-interfaces-and-unions-7dd5be35de0d

is a good guide going into more detail.

Comment: Helped me wrap my head around fragments & graphql in general, thank you :)